# Búsqueda de la fila con 10 casillas llenas en Prolog

Tags: prolog

Tengo esta matriz y deseo saber cual es la fila con todas las casillas llenas, las X son espacios.

```
[[1,0,X,1,0,0,1,0,1,X],
[1,1,0,X,X,1,0,0,1,0],
[1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]].
```

tengo este algoritmo hecho pero no me da la fila

`busqueda10Casillas(_,11,X).
 busqueda10Casillas(Matriz,1,X) :- F1 is 1 + 10,cant1MatrizFila(1,Matriz,1,Cant),Cant==5,cant1MatrizFila(0,Matriz,1,Cant),Cant==5,busqueda10Casillas(Matriz,F1,F),!.
busqueda10Casillas(Matriz,F,F):- F1 is 1 + 10,cant1MatrizFila(1,Matriz,F,Cant),Cant==5,cant0MatrizFila(0,Matriz,F,Cant),Cant==5,busqueda10Casillas(Matriz,F1,F),!.
busqueda10Casillas(Matriz,F,F):- F1 is F + 1,busqueda10Casillas(Matriz,F1,F1),!.`

en donde si llego a encontrar la primera fila con 10 posiciones llenas entonces me devuelva dicha fila

tengo el algoritmo que me indica eso

```
cant1MatrizColumna(N,[X|_],1,Cant) :- cantRep(N,X,Cant). 
cant1MatrizColumna(N,[_|Ys],F,Cant) :- F1 is F - 
1,cant1MatrizColumna(N,Ys,F1,Cant).

cantRep(_,[],0).  
cantRep(X,[X1|R],Cant):- cantRep(X,R,Cant1),X == X1 -> Cant is Cant1+1,!.
cantRep(X,[_|R],Cant):-  cantRep(X,R,Cant),!.
```

que me devuelve la cantidad de veces que se repite un elemento en una lista y como en cada fila debo tener 5 unos y 5 ceros entonces lo igualo a 5 y con eso se que tiene las 5 posiciones llenas pero estoy haciendo algo malo en el método de búsqueda que cuando le paso por parámetro la matriz la fila inicial que es 1 y el valor en donde quiero que lo instacie me devuelve siempre 1.

Comment: Me parece un error tipográfico, ya que las letras mayúsculas en prolog se usan para Variables, así que si mandas un arreglo para consulkta con mayúsculas tratará de resolver el valor de esas X. Lo recomendable en este caso creo que es poner espacios literalmente `' '`. Ahora si no es el caso, te recomiendo agregar la forma en que estás consultando tus reglas.